# How to list Guild's Roles with filter on role.name?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Using Discord.js, is there any way to list a guild's roles, filtering them by name?

For example, if someone typed `!search member`, the bot would reply with a numbered list of all roles that have or contain the string "member".

In this case, `!search` is just the command that triggers the bot to filter the roles.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO, please read the tour first to make sure you give a good question https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: sorry for that because im new here.

Comment: No problem, everyone have a start point ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
const roles = Member.roles
    .filter(r => r.id !== message.guild.id)
    .map(r => r).join(", ") || 'none';
```

Using This will Help You! :)

Comment: Sorry, but i need to list the guild's roles 
not member's roles
and that roles to be listed.. Just the roles witch named with numers. 1.2.3.4 etc.
this coded above listed the all roles in guild. I need to filter the roles named with numbers only